# Changing baseline name

Tags: linux, clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I have tried making a new baseline but the label name looked clumsy so I wanted to remove the baseline but it takes lot of time.

What's the safest way to change the baseline label?

Tried this:

```
cleartool rmbl <baseline>@/myVobs
```

Can we do this:

```
cleartool rename <old-baseline>@/myVobs <new-baseline>@/myVobs
```

But renaming is only restricted to objects and not baselines. Can anybody clarify this?

Answer (score 0):

You can rename a baseline ([`cleartool rename`](https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_rename.htm)):

```
cleartool rename baseline:yourBaseline@\YourPvob newName
```

You need to use the fully qualified name, whic here is a baseline selector:
`baseline:baseline-name[@vob-selector]`.

Note that before CC7.1, renaming a baseline [didn't change its associated label type](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21251401).
With CC7.1+, this is no longer the case, and a simple rename is enough.

Comment: Thanks. but the syntax needs both old and new name, right?

Comment: @user3088983 Yes, I forgot the "new name" part. You should be able to specify just the new name (without having to prefix it with '`baseline:`' and suffix it with the `@\Pvob`)